# Limit JSON file to 20 objects with php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a form when submitted creates a JSON file. I am trying to limit the JSON file to 20 objects. Basically I am trying to display the top 20 test scores. The score submitted should replace the the lowest score out of the 20. It's been years since I've played with php any help would be greatly appreciated.

The JSON file I am creating with php looks like the following:

```
[
   {
    "private": "private value",
    "testscore": "private value"
   }
]
```

My php file looks like this:

```
<?php

// name of file I am saving
$filetxt = 'data/private.json';

if (is_ajax()) {
if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) {
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    $data = array(
        'private'=> $_POST['private'],
        'private'=> $_POST['private'],
        'finalscore'=> floatval($_POST['final-score-value']),
    );

    $filetxt = 'data/private.json';

    // to store all form data
    $arr_data = array();

    // check if the file exists
    if(file_exists($filetxt)) {
        // gets json-data from file
        $jsondata = file_get_contents($filetxt);

        // converts json string into array
        $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    }

    // appends the array with new form data
    $arr_data[] = $data;

    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data);

    // saves the json string in "private.json"
    if(file_put_contents('data/private.json', $jsondata));
}
}

function is_ajax() {
return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&      
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

?>
```

Comment: Is your data ordered already? If it is, you can use for example `array_slice()` on `$arr_data` to reduce it to what you need. Otherwise you'd need to sort it first and then slice it. By the way, a database seems a more logical solution than a file containing json.

Comment: @jeroen I am sorting it on the client side, I could try and sort it in php. I will give that a try.

Comment: Doesn't really matter where you sort it. Just use `array_slice` once it's sorted.

Comment: I notice that you add an element to the data you get from the file, so you would need to sort it right away in php because otherwise the results (top-20) might not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't append.  If it's sorted ascending by `finalscore` then replace the first element (lowest `finalscore`):

```
$arr_data[0] = $data;
```

If sorted descending then replace the last element (lowest `finalscore`):

```
$arr_data[count($arr_data)-1] = $data;
```

If it's not sorted in the file, then something like:

```
array_multisort(array_column($arr_data, 'score'), SORT_DESC, $arr_data);
```

Comment: this only works if the submitted score happens to be in 20th position. Much more likely the position of the newly submitted score is not known at this point, so instead should just be appended, **then** the array should be sorted and the 1st 20 elements saved back to file

Comment: Except they stated that it is sorted on the client side.

Comment: oh yes, i didnt see the comment, sorry